# Express you are willing to share time with somebody you do not know yet

Tags: spoken-english

I want to invite somebody else to spend some time, casually, welcoming if the other person can put it in their schedule.
The first thing I came up with [with context]:

> [I will be around until Friday.]
>   Let me know if you want to share some time.

Sent it, but now came here since as I re-read it, it sounded a bit strange to me.
Is there a better way to express this intent?

Comment: Possibly, "**spend some time together**" or "**spare some of your time to play football**"

Comment: "spend" or "spare" is used over "share" if I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yup. I would say **share** isn't the best word to use with time. I simply cannot imaging the action of sharing time, whereas spending time and sparing time are okay.

Comment: It might sound more natural to say, "Let me know if you want to *get together.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your interest sound genuine, instead of trying to say that schedules are more important. If you and another really want to meet, you will bend your schedules.

> I would like to meet you, the sooner the better because I will be away
>   from Friday.

Only use a schedule as an excuse not to meet — not for saying you have more important matters... well unless you want to play it cool and not come on too strong.

Comment: I already love this stack exchange board... And I just got started :) Thanks for your answer.